# Unable to migrate old project on new computer

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc, overflowexception

I am getting an error when I try to migrate a old project on my new computer. On the old computer the database worked fine. The content of the database is of little importance, thats why I didnt bring the old database to the new computer as a .bak file. Its a school project.

I am working In:

VS 2015.

ASP.NET Core

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "type": "platform"
},

"frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.0": {
  "imports": [
    "dotnet5.6",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}
  },
```

This is the error code from the VS PackedManager:

> System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.    at System.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIOpenSyncExWrapper(SNI_CLIENT_CONSUMER_INFO& pClientConsumerInfo, IntPtr& ppConn)
>       at System.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIOpenSyncEx(ConsumerInfo consumerInfo, String constring, IntPtr& pConn, Byte[] spnBuffer, Byte[] instanceName, Boolean fOverrideCache, Boolean fSync, Int32 timeout, Boolean fParallel)
>       at System.Data.SqlClient.SNIHandle..ctor(ConsumerInfo myInfo, String serverName, Byte[] spnBuffer, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int32 timeout, Byte[]& instanceName, Boolean flushCache, Boolean fSync, Boolean fParallel)
>       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.CreatePhysicalSNIHandle(String serverName, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Byte[]& instanceName, Byte[] spnBuffer, Boolean flushCache, Boolean async, Boolean fParallel) 
>       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) 
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) 
>       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) 
>       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) 
>       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessio nData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
>       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) 
>       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) 
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) 
>       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) 
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) 
>       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) 
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open() 
>       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists) 
>       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
>       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration) 
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.DatabaseUpdateCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0()
>       at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
>       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args) 
>    Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

I have searched for solutions on the web, but didnt find anything I thought I could use. I am using SSMS 2016 latest version to work with the database.

Good to know is that I am currently working in school whith Virtual machines on the same computer. I am using VMWare and there is a SQL Server Express 2012 installed on the WAC server on the virtual machine. i dont know if that has any npact on my current problem but I figure the more you know the better you can help. The Virtual machines are not running while I work on this problem.

Tell me if there is anything else you would like to se frpm my code.

Comment: `Thats why I didnt bring the old database to the new computer` - Looks like it might not like the database. Have you tried bringing the old database over and using it to see if you get the same issue?

Comment: Unfortuantly the old database does not exist any more. Wiped the old computer and sold it.

Comment: From what I found on this exact error when thrown at `System.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper` it seems to come down to an incompatible or corrupted database.

Comment: Delete migrations folder in your solution -> Create new empty database -> Change connection string to new database connection -> `dotnet ef migrations add Initial` -> `dotnet ef database update` -> Add data to your DB and have fun

Comment: Hmm. Tried it. But same error message.

Comment: @Fran how did you solve incompatible or corrupt database? Do you know if visual studio saves any files related to the old database like keys that doesn't match when I try to migrate on the new computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue finally. I did a complete reset of windows 10. And installed VS 2017. Then it all worked. I also did a fresh test project and tried to migrate it. But the same problem kept returning. So I figured it had to be some broken files somewhere. But as mentioned it all works now. Thanx for all the suggestions.